# In Python 2, is there a way to save a value generated by a function to be used again when the function is called the next time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that takes two values, same and add, and generates a total value of both, a spend value (80% of the sum,) and a save value (20% of the sum.) The purpose is so that I can input a certain amount of money as my same (the amount of money I had before), and everytime I receive more money, I can call the function, put the new amount of money in as the add value (the money I just gained), and skip having to count all the money and calculate a save and spend myself. The problem is I don't know how I can use the new total I calculated the next time I call the function without having to count the money and use that as the new same value the next time, which defeats the purpose of the whole program.

```
def eightovertwo(same,add): # takes two values, adds them, then gives an 80% and 20% value
  if same == 'none' or same == 'nil':
    print ("") # ?
  total = float(same + add)
  print ("Your total is:" + " " + str(total))
  total /= 10
  spend = total
  save = total
  spend *= 8
  save *= 2
  print ("Your spend is:" + " " + str(spend))
  print ("Your save is:" + " " + str(save))

eightovertwo(0, 25)
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a `generator` - a type of Python function designed for these things. Or you could just use a global variable.

Comment: the question is, do you want to preserve values between different program runs or just between two calls of the function within the same run? Both are achievable, btw

Comment: I want to preserve values between different program runs. How is it achievable?